# Size of ASP.NET View State in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewstate

I would like to have a JavaScript Function that tells me the size of the View State in my ASP.NET pages.

I have googled around but the few solutions I found don't seem to be working for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should tell you how many characters are there stored in the viewstate:

```
alert(document.getElementById('__VIEWSTATE').value.length)
```

Because the ViewState is simply a string that's been base64-encoded and in general it's always stored in a hidden element with id `__VIEWSTATE`, unless you have your site configured to chunk the ViewState in pieces, in which cases, you may have one or more hidden variables with Ids like `__VIEWSTATE_0`, `__VIEWSTATE_1` and so on.

Comment: document.getElementById('__VIEWSTATE') is returning null

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate is stored in `<input type="hidden" />` with the `id` of "__VIEWSTATE". You can get it size by running

```
var iSize = document.getElementById('__VIEWSTATE').value.length;
```